# Not enough space for the widget

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

such a problem. If you remove the date picker button, then everything works fine. However, if it is, then you can go to the second form only with a tab. Clicking on it does not work, as if there is simply not enough space. What is the problem and how to solve it?

Form -

```
Form(
                  key: _formKey,
                  child: Column(
                    children: [
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _creatorEditingController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          hintText: 'Кто создал',
                        ),
                      ),
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _executorEditingController,
                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                          icon: Icon(Icons.person),
                          hintText: 'Кто выполнил',
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
```

Datepicker -

```
ElevatedButton(
                  child: Text("$quoteStartDate"),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    var selectedFirstDate = await DatePicker.showSimpleDatePicker(
                      context,
                      initialDate: DateFormat.yMMMd().parse(quoteStartDate),
// firstDate: DateFormat.yMMMd().parse(quoteStartDate),
                      firstDate: DateTime(2022),
                      lastDate: DateTime(2030),
                      dateFormat: "yyyy-MMMM-dd",
                      locale: DateTimePickerLocale.ru,
                      looping: true,
                    );

                    print("My date is picked $selectedFirstDate");

                    setState(() {
                      setState(() {
                        quoteStartDate =
                            DateFormat.yMMMd().format(selectedFirstDate!);

                        print("My quoteStartDate is picked $quoteStartDate");

                        endPeriod = DateFormat.yMMMd()
                            .format(selectedFirstDate.add(Duration(days: 30)))
                            .toString();
                        // oneYear = selectedFirstDate.add(Duration(days: 29));
                      });
                    });
                  },
                ),
```

result -

[image: photo]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap your Scaffold body with `SingleChildScrollView`.

```dart
return Scaffold(
  resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: ....
```

If you are having fixed height on TextFiled, remove it

Comment: It didn't work for me

Comment: can you include full snippet of scaffold

Comment: Should I add code to a third-party resource? Or right here?

Comment: Try current , if fails you need to provide [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that can be run and reproduce the error

Comment: https://dpaste.org/YscgZ here is my code

Comment: Can you shift `SingleChildScrollView` on body on `Container` and include `resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,` on scaffold

Comment: I don't quite understand you, do I need to do this? 
`return Scaffold(
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15),` ...

Comment: I understand you, yes, it solved my problem!

Comment: Add answer to resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false and I will mark it as solved

Comment: Yes it will prevent the widget to resize and have scrollable while it needed

Answer (score 0):

try this time picker in material when  onPressed
its work good in your code

```
await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(2010),
  lastDate: DateTime(2025),
);
```

[image]

then do what you want